# Php API json_encode coding not responding to MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, api, jsonencoder

I am trying to get a response from my api coding but it does not return any results even when the code is true

Here is my code

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
function api($id, $token, $to) {
    $result=$conn->prepare('select * from users where id=:user');
    $result->bindParam(':user', $id);
    $result->execute();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $credit=$row['balance'];
        $pin=$row['pin'];
    }
    $sj = $conn->prepare("SELECT number FROM users WHERE number = :number");
    $sj->bindParam(":number", $to);
    $sj->execute();
    if($sj->rowCount()<1){
        $a=array('code'=>'0', 'text'=>'not working');
        return json_encode($a);
    }
    elseif($token ==$pin)
    {
        $a=array('code'=>'10', 'text'=>'not working');
        return json_encode($a);
    }
    else {
        $a=array('code'=>'1', 'text'=>'ok');
        return json_encode($a);
    }
}
$id=$_GET['id'];
$token=$_GET['token'];
$to=$_GET['to'];
$a=api($id, $token, $to);

echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Have you check your Apache / Nginx / php-fpm logs and see any error?

Comment: Yes but could not not found any

Comment: when you echo $id, $token etc. do you get any values

Comment: Yes I get the returns is Okay